# How to do dependency injection to express-graphql resolvers while keeping access to the request object?

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I'm using express-graphql in my nodejs app.

In order to get access to the database from the resolvers, I have created an object called `ProjectHandler` (which handles a table in the database called `projects`) and I'm injecting it to the resolvers by changing the `context` when creating the `express-graphql` instance, like so:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true,
  context: {projectsHandler}
}))
```

problem is, this replaces the default context from being a representation of the request object, preventing me from accessing session information.

The thing is, that I need both the session information and the project handler. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphqlHTTP` function returns an express `middleware` so in order to pass a custom `context` with the `request` object in it we'll have to wrap that function with our own `middleware`, and activate the `graphqlHTTP` `middleware`

this code below should work (haven't tried tough):

```
 app.use('/graphql', (request, response) => {
     return graphqlHTTP({
        schema,
        graphiql: true,
        context: {
            projectsHandler,
            request
        }
     })(request, response);
 })
```

Comment: It does :) I actually solved it 2 hours ago exactly like that! (the last parentases - calling the function - are actually not necessary though, just having the options argument as a function is suffice, it's being called every request by express-graphql)